# How to alternately unable/disable Excel sheet fields using PHPExcel in php

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is how I am trying to unable/disable certain cells in my Excel sheet using PHPExcel, but its not working this way...either the sheet fully locked or fully writable.

My code -

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Swapnesh Sinha")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Swapnesh Sinha")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Student Grid Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Student Grid Document")
                             ->setDescription("Student document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Student Data");

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Swapnesh');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Vikas');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(false); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Sachin');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$filename = "Student-data-sheet".".xlsx";
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

I am trying Swapnesh/Vikas content not to be modified but Sachin can be modify accordingly.

> // This should be enabled in order to enable any of the following!
>   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

And i am using this but could not able to make it..let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: Did you succeed to disable cell editing? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:B1')
    ->getProtection()->setLocked(
        PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
    );
```

**EDIT**

```
// Set the entire worksheet to locked
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
// Unprotect those cells that you want to make editable
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A2:B2')
    ->getProtection()->setLocked(
        PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED
    );
```

Don't reset the sheet-level changes afterwards

Comment: I tried this but still no help -----    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Swapnesh');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Vikas');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(false); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(false);

Comment: what I was trying to make A1 & B1 not editable while I can edit C1